# Cuantificar número de valores disponibles en un dataframe según el tiempo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe (de muchos valores) el cual recoge datos diezminutales. La fecha y hora estan en la columna "Timestamp". El problema es que hay veces que como en el siguiente ejemplo, no existe el dato (a las 12:10).

```
                  Timestamp  posAllTime             Xt1                  PT2
0       2020-06-13 11:30:00           1           3.45851              5.458466
1       2020-06-13 11:40:00           2           3.486813             6.384967
2       2020-06-13 11:50:00           3           4.132464             6.836622
3       2020-06-13 12:00:00           4           4.48934              5.32188
4       2020-06-13 12:20:00           5           4.468308             5.814852
...                     ...         ...              ...                 ...
82494   2020-12-25 23:20:00       40829           11.502346            10.453274
```

Me gustaría saber cual es el porcentaje de datos de los que dispongo. Con la siguiente función calculo el número de filas que hay:

```
print(data1.shape[0])
```

Para calcular el número de datos que debería haber, debería calcular el número de diezminutales que hay entre la primera fecha y la última, pero no se cómo se hace con fechas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la librería datetime, con la que puedes hacer diferentes operaciones con fechas. Te pongo un ejemplo partiendo de un DataFrame de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'fechas':['2020-06-13 11:30:00','2020-06-13 11:50:00','2020-06-13 12:00:00','2020-06-13 12:20:00']})
```

De la siguiente forma:

```
                fechas
0  2020-06-13 11:30:00
1  2020-06-13 11:50:00
2  2020-06-13 12:00:00
3  2020-06-13 12:20:00
```

En primer lugar si tu columna no es de tipo fecha deberás convertirla:

```
df['fechas']= pd.to_datetime(df['fechas'])
```

Te creas un intervalo de 10 minutos con `timedelta` con el que podrás dividir tu ultimo timstamp menos el primero:

```
diezmin = timedelta(minutes=10)
```

Ya puedes restar la fecha menor a la mayor y dividirlo entre los diez minutos (no te olvides de sumarle 1).

```
freal = df.shape[0] #Cuantas filas tenemos realmente
fdeb = 1+(df.iloc[-1]['fechas']-df.iloc[0]['fechas'])/diezmin #Cuantas filas deberíamos tener
```

ya solo te quedaría dividir:

```
print(freal/fdeb) #En este caso te daría 0.666666
```

**Aclaración**

Para que se entienda por qué hay que sumar 1 al calcular `fdeb`, la respuesta rápida es porque estamos comparando intervalos de tiempo con filas.

Para desarrollarlo un poco:

Entre la primera hora del ejemplo `11:30:00` y la última `12:20:00` debería haber 6 datos (aunque inicialmente no lo sabemos, es el dato que queremos sacar con el código):

```
11:30:00
11:40:00
11:50:00
12:00:00
12:10:00
12:20:00
```

Pero si nos fijamos hay solo 5 intervalos, es decir, uno menos.

Por ahora lo único que podemos hacer es calcular cuantos minutos hay de diferencia entre la hora final y la inicial `12:20:00 - 11:30:00` que nos da `00:50:00` como sabemos que los datos están distanciados 10 minutos, dividimos estos 50 minutos entre 10 minutos, que nos daría 5.

Pero este 5 no es el número de datos que debería haber, sino el número de intervalos que debería haber, por eso hay que sumarle uno, para obtener el número de filas que debería haber.

Y ya solo quedaría dividir el número de filas que realmente tenemos, entre el número de filas que debería haber.

Comment: Parece que funciona, una vez logre implementar a todos los dataframes que tengo te lo comento. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te acuerdas por que le sumabas el 1?

Comment: He añadido una aclaración sobre lo de sumar uno, a ver si es suficiente.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.